# Issue with people accessing my gh-pages on Github

Tags: html, css, git, hosting, github-pages

So I created a gh-pages repo in Github to host my portfolio but whenever someone goes there they have to log into Github to view. Gh-pages are supposed to be public so I have no idea why this is happening. My portfolio is just html and css.
Here's a link to the page :　https://github.iu.edu/pages/iford/Portfolio/．

Comment: This is a weird github pages url. Shouldn't it be something like http://iford.github.io/Portfolio ?

Comment: I set up my github account through my school's github enterprise, thinking about it would make sense that the school wouldn't allow public hosting on their git. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you using Github Enterprise??

Comment: Yes, unfortunately my understanding of Github is a little lacking but thank you I believe you've led me to my answer, if I have any more issues I'll be back

Answer (score 0):

So the github I account I used to setup the portfolio was on a server running Github Enterprise that is why it wasn't truly "public". To fix this I just created a new github account through github (not an enterprise edition) and created a new repo for the page there. Done.